# Из панели задач пропала иконка управления USB (Windows-10-64)

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-10, usb

Добрый день.

Есть ноутбук ACER Pentium четырехъядерный довольно новый (CPU N3540 покупал полтора года назад). На нем стояла Windows-8 после покупки она проапгрейдилась до Windows-10-64 Home Edition. Сегодня с утра пропала иконка на панели задач, которая управляла отключением USB устройств. Теперь, чтобы отключить флешку, приходится лазать в настройки.

Вопрос:

Как вернуть на место в панели задач иконку, которая управляла отключением USB устройств?

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ларчик просто открывался. Надо во время работы Windows подключить USB накопитель. В моем случае это был внешний USB диск. Тогда на панели задач появляется иконка управления USB устройствами.

PS. Вроде бы media устройства не вызывают появления такой иконки. Нужно именно store устройство.